# Proper aliasing of spatial columns in SQL

Tags: sql, optimization, alias

Referencing the alias `length_road` in the `WHERE` clause does not seem to be allowed. Does this query as written cause the `ST_LENGTH` operation to be run more than once per record, and if so, how can that be avoided?

```
SELECT
  roads_nat.*,
  ST_LENGTH(roads_nat.road_geom) AS length_road
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_roads.us_national_roads` AS roads_nat
WHERE
  ST_LENGTH(roads_nat.road_geom) > 1000 -- vs. length_road > 1000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a question about SQL column aliasing, not just big query ... the alias can only be used on a column name, not on a column in a where clause. If you created a subquery, you would reference the alias of the length_road in the where clause of the subquery instead.

```
select * from (
    SELECT
      roads_nat.*,
      ST_LENGTH(roads_nat.road_geom) AS length_road
    FROM
      `bigquery-public-data.geo_us_roads.us_national_roads` AS roads_nat

) as main 

WHERE main.length_road > 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

In PostGIS, since `st_length` is immutable, it will be called once only per row. This is true regardless of the position of the call (in the `select` and/or the `where`)

The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html) says

> IMMUTABLE indicates that the function cannot modify the database and
>   always returns the same result when given the same argument values;
>   that is, it does not do database lookups or otherwise use information
>   not directly present in its argument list. **If this option is given,
>   any call of the function with all-constant arguments can be
>   immediately replaced with the function value.**

When used against a table row, each row is considered constant. So if you call the same function several times on the same row, the function will be evaluated once only.

Comment: Thanks JGH. I was wondering if something like this was the case independent of aliasing but was not sure of the terminology. This is really helpful.